# How do I get the border-bottom to display?

Tags: css

I have styled a div (tried as a span as well) to to add a border-bottom, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code I've used:

```
.Category_Sub_Header_Title {
  color: #c3a310;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px single #c3a310;
}
```

The reference is: http://anniversary.cinemasight.com/

In the section below the drop-down menu, I have four titles: "Top Tens," "Face-Off," "Today in Oscar History" and "Polls" all of which should be bottom bordered to separate them from the post links.

I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong to cause the div not to add the bottom border. Any ideas?

Comment: No...it's very clear..but it's poorly researched.

Comment: People are downvoting this question because it is a simple mistake you can correct by re-reading the CSS specifications carefully. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom_style.asp in particular.

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time. There's no reason to be condescending about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS border-style **single** does not exist; you might looking for `solid`.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style).

Comment: I had it blank before and it didn't work, so I swapped it out. I had used double elsewhere and foolishly forgotten that there was no single. Thanks  for the reminder. This fixed the problem.